# helm upgrade proxy parameters

Tags: linux, proxy, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i have a problem. i want to install helm on the kubernetes but when i want run this command `helm init --upgrade` but i have this error :

```
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Error: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not 
a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-
charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: dial tcp 216.58.197.80:443: i/o 
timeout
```

I suppose that the proxy settings didn't set, but I do not find how to do it.

an idea ?

thank's for your help,

sincerely,

Killer_Minet

Comment: see - https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/804

Comment: i didn't add : http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts because the .helm directory doesn't exist. When i execute `helm init` command, the .helm directory doesn't create.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you have an internal proxy? If so, you want to set the `https_proxy` environment as `https_proxy=<your proxy> helm init --upgrade`. You can also set it globally as `export https_proxy=<your proxy>`.